# (Symfony\Form) prevent form fields from being generated automaticly

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a twig-template. It iterates through the collection of forms (form.MeteringCodes). The problem is, i need to display only the value of one field and when i dont use "form_row(...)" explicitly, **symfony generates the field automaticly at the end of the form**.

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
...
            <tbody>
                {% for metCode in form.MeteringCodes %}
                    {{ form_row(metCode.id) }}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ metCode.desc.vars.value }} {# <-- Here is the pure value #}</td>
                    <td>{{ form_row(metCode.sdesc) }}</td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">{{ form_row(metCode.type) }}</td>
                    <td style="width:15%;">{{ form_row(metCode.state) }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
...
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I see two ways. One is to disable this "auto generating" behaviour. The second might be if i just get the value from the original object itself, without defining it as a field (if its possible).

Collection type itself:

```
class MeteringCodeType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('id', 'hidden');
        $builder->add('desc', 'text', ['label' => false, 'disabled' => true]);
        $builder->add('sdesc', 'text', ['label' => false]);
        $builder->add('type', 'choice', ['choices'  => array('L' => '...', 'D' => '...', 'N' => '...'), 'label' => false]);
        $builder->add('state', 'text', ['label' => false]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'app\models\MeteringCode',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'MeteringCode';
    }
}
```

I dont want to use some workarounds like a hidden field.

Answer (score 14):

You can pass additional argument to `form_end()` call:

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This not the best option. This will cause that the crf token isnt rendered and your protection against xss is disabled. Its better to write a new form class (src/Form/xxxType) where you only add the one field that you need. Or to make your current form class more dynamic.

Comment: That is correct, but what is an alternative to this (except making form dynamic)?

Comment: You can still render the CSRF token by using `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` but as @Frankbeen suggested it's better to write a new form class.

Answer (score 4):

Nice approach @Sergey Bratenkov I wanted it to show it with a text field in read only mode because my field was an **entity field**. This is what I used

```
<input type="text" value="{{ formulario.vars.value.getJuego() }}" readonly="readonly"/>

{% do formulario.juego.setRendered %}
```

with setRendered functionality you tell twig to stop rendering the field automatically after using form_start.

Answer (score 1):

Thx everybody. I found the solution. 
I removed the field from the form itself, and accessing the value through the getter of an original object. Another benefit is that the field does not need to be rendered at all.

> {{ metCode.vars.value.getDesc() }}